# Question on regular function from Kolmogorov equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I am reading about a topic on Kolmogorov equation and diffusion process. However, I am confused by the last using so called "regular function". I wonder what does this "regular function" mean here? And why do we even need to write the final equation in terms of $u$ not $F_{t}\left(x, y_{0}\right)$?

> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t} F_{t}\left(x, y_{0}\right)=\rho(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} F_{t}\left(x, y_{0}\right)+\frac{1}{2} Q(x) \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} F_{t}\left(x, y_{0}\right) \qquad(10.9.11)
> $$
> which is the Kolmogorov backward equation for stationary diffusion processes. The initial condition is given by
> $$
> \lim _{t \downarrow 0} F_{t}\left(x, y_{0}\right)= \begin{cases}1, & \text { if } x<y_{0} \\ 0, & \text { if } x>y_{0}\end{cases}
> $$
> For a reasonably regular function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, define
> $$
> u(t, x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) P_{t}(x, d y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) d F_{t}(x, y) .
> $$
> It follows from Equation (10.9.11) that $u$ satisfies the following equation:
> $$
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\mathcal{A} u, \quad u(0, x)=f(x)
> $$

Comment: A function will be 'reasonably regular' as soon as the integral for $u$ is well-defined and in particular finite.

Comment: @Tobsn But why do we need such function '$u(t,x)$'? For finding out more solutions of the KBE?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'need'. $u$ solves the Cauchy- problem with initial datum $f$.

Comment: @Tobsn (1)So do you mean "the integral for $\mathbb{u}$ is well-defined and in particular finite" is some kind of definition for 'reasonably regular'? (2)In the KBE(10.9.11), the solution is $\mathbb{F}$, somehow, we extend the solution by integrating some regular function wrt. $\mathbb{F}$. Does this $\mathbb{u}$ really satisfy the KBE(10.9.11)? I understand that we may have more solution so we try to extend it, but why integration would be the method to find more general solution?

Comment: There is no precise definition for 'reasonably regular' functions. Typically mathematicians use this term when being lazy and in order to avoid unnecessary technicalities. Bounded, continuous functions for instance would certainly be 'reasonably regular'. But one could choose more genral functions, too. Yes, $u$ also satisfies 10.9.11 -that's just a classical consequence of how differential operators act on convolutions.

Comment: @Tobsn Can I say a function has higher regularity if it has higher order of continuous differentiability?